# Taylor series of $\ln{\sqrt[4]{\frac{x-2}{5-x}}}$ to $o((x-x_0)^n)$ when $x_0 = 3$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Well I have tried to get it as
$$f(x) = f(x_0) + \frac{f'(x_0)(x-x_0)}{1!} + \frac{f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2}{2!} + ... + o((x-x_0)^n)$$
and got wrong results:

First: $$f'(x) = \frac{3}{4(x-2)(5-x)}$$ 
Second: $$f''(x) = \frac{3(2x-7)}{4(x-2)^2(5-x)^2} , $$
Third: $$f'''(x) = \frac{3}{4}*\frac{2(x-2)(5-x) - 2(5-x)(2x-7) + 2(x-2)(2x-7)}{(x-2)^3(5-x)^3}$$

Then I have tried changing it to $$\ln{\sqrt[4]{\frac{x-2}{5-x}}} = \frac{ln{(x-2)}}{4} - \frac{ln{(5-x)}}{4}$$ and got nothing useful. So I need an advice how to start. Or at least a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, set $x-3=t$ so the computations will possibly be easier; then note that $x=t+3$ and that
$$
\ln{\sqrt[4]{\frac{x-2}{5-x}}}=
\frac{1}{4}\ln(1+t)-\frac{1}{4}\ln(2-t)=
\frac{1}{4}\ln(1+t)-\frac{\ln{2}}{4}-
\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(1-\frac{t}{2}\right)
$$
Now just use the series expansion of $\ln(1+z)$ around $z=0$.

Comment: Just curious, but why is the form on the right-hand side equation in this answer easier to expand than the form given in the OP as $\frac14 \log(x-2)-\frac14 \log(5-x)$?

Comment: @Dr.MV Because the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+x)$ is known.

Comment: Yes, it is .  And the Taylor series for $\log(x)$ is known.  I'm not trying to be a thorn here.  Just curious as to your thinking here.  ;-)) - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV I just prefer to remember one easy formula than a more complex one, together with a rather simple reduction process. Not a big deal, though.

Comment: Greg, that makes sense.  And yes, no big deal.  +1 - Mark

Answer (score 0):

Answer is $$-\frac{ln2}{4} + \sum^n_{k=1}{\frac{(-1)^{k-1} + 2^{-k}(x-3)^k}{4k}} + o((x-3)^n)$$